# iOS UIView get frame after rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, size, orientation, frame

I'm trying to get the size of my `UIView` after the orientation changes. In my view controller I implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and call `setNeedsLayout:` on my view. In my view's `layoutSubviews` method, it tries to perform some logic based on its new frame size post rotation, but the frame size has not been updated to reflect the new orientation (e.g. it is still 768x1024 instead of 1024x768 after moving to landscape).

How do I get the updated frame size?

Comment: have you tried using bounds instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just going to answer with what Luis Oscar said so that the question shows up as answered.
The solution is to access the "bounds" property rather than "frame".

Answer (score 2):

Please try this method.This method will call automatically at the time of rotation.Hope this may help you. Thanks.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
        NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this for me is that the view in question is several levels down from the view controller (as in a subview of a subview of the viewcontroller's view). I'm not sure how I could get this information from the view controller to the view in a reasonable manner.